# Meteor : wait for a callback

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

WHen I create an account on my Meteor app, I check in several time the validity  of each element. Then I create the user. If no error appeared, I show a success div, and an error one on the other case.

```
Accounts.createUser(options ,function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log("rorororororroro");
        if(err.message == "Email already exists. [403]"){
          Session.set('error', regAlert("This email adress already exists", tmpl));
        }else{
          Session.set('error', regAlert("Sorry, but an unidentified error occured. Please retry later. If the error persists, contact the support"));
        }
      }else if(Meteor.call('talknameIsAvailable', talkname)){
        Session.set('error', regAlert("A user with this talkname already exists", tmpl));
      }
    });
    if(!Session.get('error')){
      $('#register-success').show("slow");
      //console.log("[SUCCESS] Account created");
      //document.location.href="/";
    }else{
      $('#register-error').show("slow");
    }
```

The problem is that I always show the success div, as the last `if / else` is computed before the callback set the error session var when the email is already used.

What's the best way in Meteor to handle this case ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

When Session.get("error") is undefined, (!Session.get("error")) returns true.

try:

```
if (Session.get("error") !== void 0) {

}
```

Comment: the error session var il defined at the start of the function to false. While the function is being computed, it might set it to true if something goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I added `.wait()` at the end of the `createUser` function :

```
Accounts.createUser(options ,function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log("rorororororroro");
    if(err.message == "Email already exists. [403]"){
      Session.set('error', regAlert("This email adress already exists", tmpl));
    }else{
      Session.set('error', regAlert("Sorry, but an unidentified error occured. Please retry later. If the error persists, contact the support"));
    }
  }else if(Meteor.call('talknameIsAvailable', talkname)){
    Session.set('error', regAlert("A user with this talkname already exists", tmpl));
  }
}).wait();
```